# How to dump and compress MySQL database in Windows only using command line

Tags: windows, compression, mysqldump

Is it possible to backup and compress just like in Linux: 
`mysqldump --all-databases | lzma > all.sql.gz`

I only have `smb://` and `cmd.exe` access via `winexe`, so no GUI (remote desktop is not enabled, it requires kerberos or something), and `phpmyadmin` are too slow/timeout when dumping 1.2GB database.

Comment: mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:\[filename].sql did that cause any issues to you?

Comment: the problem would be, it's uncompressed..

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution, download any command line compression utility, for example: [xz](http://tukaani.org/xz/) (it gives good compression ration: from `1.2GB` database size to just `100MB`), put it on mysql directory using `smb://`, then run `cmd.exe`, change directory to the mysql directory using `cd`, then execute:

```
mysqldump -u user -p --all-databases | xz > all.sql.xz
```

then just copy the `100MB` backup file to Linux box via `smb://`

**EDIT**: actually it's `>2GB` when exported to `.sql`, so I do really need the compression:

```
$ xz --list mysql-all_20141128_2012.sql.xz 
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename
    1       1     96.2 MiB  2,297.7 MiB  0.042  CRC64   mysql-all_20141128_2012.sql.xz
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214437/php-mysqldump-and-zip-7z this has a 7zip version